# probability in javascript help?

Tags: javascript, math

Sorry, I'm new to JS and can't seem to figure this out: how would I do probability?

I have absolutely no idea, but I'd like to do something: out of 100% chance, maybe 0.7% chance to execute function `e();` and 30% chance to execute function `d();` and so on - they will add up to 100% exactly with a different function for each, but I haven't figured out exactly how to do this in any form.

What I found is mostly strange high school math tutorials "powered by" Javascriptkit or something.

Comment: are these set probabilities? as in, are you going to have a table of probabilities that link to functions? or are they dynamic, based on input?

Comment: It's set probability, with table that links to function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For instance we define a number of functions

```
function a () { return 0; }
function b () { return 1; }
function c () { return 2; }

var probas = [ 20, 70, 10 ]; // 20%, 70% and 10%
var funcs = [ a, b, c ]; // the functions array
```

That generic function works for any number of functions, it executes it and return the result:

```
function randexec()
{
  var ar = [];
  var i,sum = 0;


  // that following initialization loop could be done only once above that
  // randexec() function, we let it here for clarity

  for (i=0 ; i<probas.length-1 ; i++) // notice the '-1'
  {
    sum += (probas[i] / 100.0);
    ar[i] = sum;
  }


  // Then we get a random number and finds where it sits inside the probabilities 
  // defined earlier

  var r = Math.random(); // returns [0,1]

  for (i=0 ; i<ar.length && r>=ar[i] ; i++) ;

  // Finally execute the function and return its result

  return (funcs[i])();
}
```

For instance, let's try with our 3 functions, 100000 tries:

```
var count = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

for (var i=0 ; i<100000 ; i++)
{
  count[randexec()]++;
}

var s = '';
var f = [ "a", "b", "c" ];

for (var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
  s += (s ? ', ':'') + f[i] + ' = ' + count[i];

alert(s);
```

The result on my Firefox

```
a = 20039, b = 70055, c = 9906
```

So *a* run about 20%, *b* ~ 70% and *c* ~ 10%.

**Edit** following comments.

If your browser has a cough with `return (funcs[i])();`, just replace the funcs array

```
var funcs = [ a, b, c ]; // the old functions array
```

with this new one (strings)

```
var funcs = [ "a", "b", "c" ]; // the new functions array
```

then replace the final line of the function `randexec()`

```
return (funcs[i])(); // old
```

with that new one

```
return eval(funcs[i]+'()');
```

Comment: For some reason, it just says `Error: funcs[i] is not a function` (for the line `return (funcs[i])();`) after adding my own arrs. The count, probas and funcs arrays are all fine, and all the functions exist. Not sure if having numbers in the fucntion names and a LOT of duplicate probabilities would matter.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't create a function name that is not in the funcs array, or, for instance, that a func name like `i` interferes with the other variables? Please try with my example. If it works, it should work with any function, as long as their name is correct, is in the funcs array and does not hide another existing variable (or, reversely, would be hidden by another variable).

Comment: Please check my **edit** it should work with any browser. (the above comment about variables hiding is still true however :-)

Comment: Eval!! Death! Surely better to do { var fun = funcs[i]; return fun() }?

Comment: As you allude to in the comment, calculate the cumulative DF instead of using the array of percentages. Then you can use bisection to find the value, although it could JIT slower. Worth it for large distributions, I think.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should help:

```
var threshhold1 = 30.5;
var threshhold2 = 70.5;
var randomNumber = random() * 100;
if (randomNumber < threshhold1) {
   func1()
}
else if (randomNumber < threshhold2) {
   func2()
}
else {
   func3()
}
```

This will execute `func1()` with 30.5% probability, `func2()` with 40%, and `func3()` with 29.5%.

You could probably do it more elegantly using a dictionary of threshholds to function pointers, and a loop that finds the first dictionary entry with a threshhold greater than `randomNumber`.

Comment: I've been trying something like this but I can't seem to get it work for a very large amount of identical amounts (a lot of 0.50%)

Comment: I was thinking something like <0.50, >0.50&&<1.0, >1&&<1.5, but that seems like it'd be unnecessarily complicated if there was a better way

Comment: Just set the threshholds to 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, ... .  You only need to check each threshhold once because once one threshhold matches the other greater threshholds won't be checked.

Answer (score 4):

```
// generate cumulative distribution function from weights
function cdf(weights) {
    // calculate total
    var total = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<weights.length; i++) {
        total += weights[i];
    }
    // generate CDF, normalizing with total
    var cumul = [];
    cumul[0] = weights[0]/total;
    for(var i=1; i<weights.length; i++) {
        cumul[i] = cumul[i-1] + (weights[i]/total);
    }
    return cumul;
}

// pick the index using the random value
function selectInd(cumul,rand) {
    for(var i=0; (i < cumul.length) && (rand > cumul[i]); ++i) {};
    return i;
}
```

Code block to use the above

```
// setup (do this once)
var weights = [70,20,10];
var cumul = cdf(weights)

// get the index and pick the function
var ran = Math.random(); // 0 : 1
var func = funcs[selectInd(cumul,ran)]; 

// call the function
var someArgVal = 5;
var myResult = func(someArgVal);

// do it in one line
var myResult = (funcs[selectInd(cumul,Math.random())])(someArgVal);
```

Simplify calling code with a reusable object

```
function CumulDistributor(cumul,funcs) {
    var funcArr = funcs;
    var cumulArr = cumul;
    function execRandomFunc(someArg) {
        var func = funcArr[selectInd(cumulArr,Math.random())];
        return func(someArg);
    }
}

// example usage
var cdistor = new CumulDistributor(cumul,funcs);
var myResult = cdistor.execRandomFunc(someArgValue);
```

Comment: This is a great function.  This solution is undersold as the weights can be any proportion.  [7,2,1] works just as well as [70,20,10].  The weights don't have to actually equal 100 which has a lot of great utility and usability.

Answer (score 2):

```
var decide = function(){ 
    var num = parseInt(Math.random() * 10) + 1; // assigns num randomly (1-10)
    num > 7 ? d() : e(); // if num > 7 call d(), else call e() 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Look up how to get random numbers in JavaScript, and then depending on where that number falls, call each function.

Comment: I looked at random function, but I couldn't really figure out how exactly to do it because it just returns random numbers and I have no clue how to compare 0.4% of a random number or something..

Comment: Find a way to get a random integer between 1 and 10, inclusive.  Then check to see if the number is 1, 2, or 3 in order to check for 30% of the cases.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would fit with the rest though - there are about 25 functions that are under 0.5%. Should I ceil or floor for 1 and 10 or does it not matter asl ong as it's consistent?

Comment: You can modify the upper/lower range of the random number to be whatever you want.  It can even return decimal numbers. The point is to use random() however you'd like to get the % chance you want to act on

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you really want is the [Javascript random() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp).

Comment: PLEASE, PLEASE, never refer people to the `W3school documentation`, Use instead the official javascript documentation in Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random maybe in 2010 this didn't exist?