# Is there a simpler way to implement a probability function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There's an [existing question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983660/probability-in-javascript-help) that deals with implementing probability in JavaScript, but I've read and re-read that answer and don't understand how it works (for my purpose) or how a simpler version of probability would look.

My goal is to do:

```
function probability(n){
    // return true / false based on probability of n / 100 
}

if(probability(70)){ // -> ~70% likely to be true
    //do something
}
```

What's the simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could do something like...

```
var probability = function(n) {
     return !!n && Math.random() <= n;
};
```

Then call it with `probability(.7)`. It works because `Math.random()` returns a number between and inclusive of `0` and `1` (see comment).

If you must use `70`, simply divide it over `100` in the body of your function.

Comment: The range of [*Math.random*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-math.random) includes 0 so in the above, `random(0)` may return true when perhaps it should not, so maybe `return !!n && Math.random() <= n`. It is good though as `random(1)` will always return *true*.

Comment: @RobG Thanks Rob, can always rely on you to fill in the blanks in my answers :)

Comment: @Alex—it's extremely rare for *Math.random* to return zero (given it has  a range of 0 to 1.0e-15 or so) so maybe it's more theoretical than practical. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

## Function Probability:

```
probability(n){
    return Math.random() < n;
}


// Example, for a 75% probability
if(probability(0.75)){
    // Code to run if success
}
```

---

If we read about [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random), it will return a number in the [0;1) interval, which includes `0` but exclude `1`, so to keep an even distribution, we need to exclude the top limit, that to say, using `<` and not `<=`.

---

Checking the upper and the lower bound probability (which are 0% or 100%):

We know that `0 ≤ Math.random() < 1` so, for a:

- Probability of 0% (when `n === 0`, it should always returning false):

  ```
  Math.random() < 0 // That actually will always return always false => Ok
  ```
- Probability of 100% (when `n === 1`, it should always returning true):

  ```
  Math.random() < 1 // That actually will always return always true => Ok
  ```

---

### Running test of the probability function

```js
// Function Probability
function probability(n){
  return Math.random() < n;
}

// Running test with a probability of 86% (for 10 000 000 iterations)
var x = 0;
var prob = 0.86;
for(let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
 if(probability(prob)){
  x += 1;
 }
}
console.log(`${x} of 10000000 given results by "Math.random()" were under ${prob}`);
console.log(`Hence so, a probability of ${x / 100000} %`);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is even more simple :

```
function probability(n) {
  return Math.random() <= n;
}
```

Comment: It's inaccurate. For `probability(0)`, the function should be **always** returning `false` ! But if ever `Math.random()` pick the value `0`, your `probability(0)` return `true` (because `0 <= 0`)