# Is it possible to randomly display questions/blocks based on some probability (not evenly) in Qualtrics?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

Is there a way to change the "evenly displayed" in Qualtrics to some probability-based randomization (either in survey flow or question randomization)?

Comment: Hi, Qualtrics has a randomizer Block that you can use. Is this what you are after?   [link](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/advanced-building/survey-flow/block-randomization/)

Comment: Not really. I need to randomize with some probability, say some questions are more likely to be displayed than others (but I can't use "edit count" because the probability is conditional on subject's choice in previous questions). I'm thinking of some javascript codes, but really don't have a clue..

Comment: Take a look at this, it looks like you can use Javascript to set/choose Q/A.  [Click Here](http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/developer-tools/custom-programming/survey-javascript-methods#AnswerChoices)

Comment: The only way I can think to do this is to setup a web service that determines the block to show and sets a piece of embedded data based on which block to show.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem eventually? 2 years later and this problem still exists.

Comment: I'm using an adaptation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983660/probability-in-javascript-help/3983830#3983830) javascript answer to a similar problem. You can plug the output into embedded data, then use the embedded data to inform which blocks or questions are shown.